# Jenkins - 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, jenkins, proxy, port

I just installed Jenkins on an Ubuntu 16.04-server via:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
apt install jenkins
```

Afterwards I changed the port in `/etc/default/jenkins` to `HTTP_PORT=8000` and added `--httpPort=$HTTP_PORT --prefix=$PREFIX` to the `/etc/default/jenkins` file and finally since I am running lots of stuff via apache already anyway I added a proxy there with:

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
ProxyPass "/jenkins" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/jenkins/" 
ProxyPassReverse "/jenkins" "http://127.0.0.1/jenkins/"
```

But when I try to access `https://MY_URL/jenkins` I get an

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /jenkins on this server.

But when I do `curl localhost:8000` on the server I do seem to get the page. So it seems to be running on that port at least, I just cannot access it via the apache (Other Proxies like /gitlab do work though the same way).

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem here?

**Edit:** When I disable `ProxyErrorOverride On` I finally see the page where I can enter the admin password but doing so redirects me to the same page again: 
`https://my_url/jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2F` -> `https://my_url/jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2F%2Fj_acegi_security_check`.
So the current config for apache looks like this:

```
## Proxy Settings
ProxyRequests          Off
ProxyPreserveHost      On
AllowEncodedSlashes    NoDecode
SetEnv                 proxy-nokeepalive 1
ProxyPass              "/gitlab"   "http://127.0.0.1:8001/gitlab/"
ProxyPassReverse       "/gitlab"   "http://127.0.0.1:8001/gitlab/"
ProxyPass              "/jenkins"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/jenkins/" nocanon
ProxyPassReverse       "/jenkins"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/jenkins/" 
ProxyPassReverse       "/jenkins"  "http://my_url/jenkins/"
RequestHeader          set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader          set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation here? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache

Comment: Yes I tried `ProxyPreserveHost On, ProxyRequests Off, AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode, SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1`. As well as adding `nocanon` to the ProxyPass. But no changes visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I finally found the error:
First `ProxyErrorOverride On` had to be removed and second I had to remove the trailing slash in the ProxyPass like this:

```
ProxyPass              "/jenkins"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/jenkins" nocanon
ProxyPassReverse       "/jenkins"  "http://127.0.0.1:8000/jenkins" 
ProxyPassReverse       "/jenkins"  "http://my_url/jenkins"
```

Interestingly gitlab did require it to work properly and jenkins does not work if the "/" are there.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe, the firewall blocks Jenkins

For me, simply run this command to resolve this issue

```
/etc/init.d/iptables.sh stop
```

Comment: Please never do that. This stops your firewall completely. If it is really necessary to open a port then add rules for it there.